# error installing joomla from server to local

Tags: joomla

error when installing joomla:
I made a site copy to my local server with akeeba; I complete all the installation steps but the end appears to maessage:

**Finalisation de la restauration
    Mise à jour de .htaccess**

[image]

what's the problem ?

Comment: Since this question doesn't involve any actual programming, maybe it would be better to ask it on http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Simba - JSE is also for Joomla programming related issues, however this needs to be aimed at the Akeeba developer, not StackExchange

Answer (score 1):

Please update to latest version of Akeeba Backup, there was a bug in previous version 5.0.4 that caused the issue you are reporting. Install the latest akeeba component and take a new backup.